# How to not render anything in react, unless data is loaded and state is completely set

Tags: reactjs

Let's consider this code:

```
const CustomersList = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [customers, setCustomers] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        // fetch customers from an API and then
        // setLoading(false)
        // setCustomers(customersArrayFromApi)
    }, [])

    return loading 
               ? 
               <div>Loading ...</div> 
               : 
               <div>
                    {customers.length === 0 
                       ? 
                       <span>No customer</span> 
                       :
                       <div>List of customers rendered here</div>
                    }
               </div>
}
```

When I `setLoading(false)` and `setCustomers(customersArrayFromApi)`, there is this tiny timeframe (even for a millisecond or less than that) that the `<span>No customer</span>` is rendered.

And we know it's because react's state setting function is async.

But I can't render JSX in `useEffect` to wait for `customers` array to be set fully.

What can I do to wait for the `customers` list to be fully set, and then render the output?

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of setState in useEffect, set the loading false after updating the customers.

> And we know it's because react's state setting function is async.

React may batch the setState calls and the state updates may happen asynchronously but **batching won't work inside async** operations like `fetch` until React 17.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // fetch customers from an API and then
  setCustomers(customersArrayFromApi); //Re-render with customers data
  setLoading(false); // Re-render with loading false
}, []);
```